# Opening a PDF file on a webview in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android Studio's Webview to convert my web app to mobile app.
my webapp has a login which shows your account's files (pdf files).
but running my default app on Android Studio, won't open these pdf files.

I read here to use Google viewer and just put the link of your PDF file just like below,

```
WebView webview=new WebView(this);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";

        webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

however, the webapp is setup wherein if you open the PDF file, it doesn't have the .pdf extension. Example is: https://mysite/files/myfiles/1234567_00/. As you see, the link does not point to a direct pdf file (.pdf extension), instead it only had "/1234567_00/". When I try to replace the link above with the URL (without .pdf extension), it won't open.

Is there a way I can get this to work? What should I change here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android webview pdf viewing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455425/android-webview-pdf-viewing)

Comment: @Zain nope that one has a different problem, but thanks for trying.